# How to use Backstretch.js with viewportWidth?

Tags: jquery, viewport, jquery-backstretch

I would like to choose images depending on viewportWidth. Unfortunately I can't get it working. Only "else"-case ist showing, so the if function doesn't work. Can you help?

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (768 < viewportWidth) {
    $.backstretch("http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/beach-sunset-traces-2730-527x350.jpg", {
        duration: 3000,
        fade: 750
    });
} else if (1024 < viewportWidth) {
    $.backstretch("http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/beach-ocean-sea-2728-527x350.jpg", {
        duration: 3000,
        fade: 750
    });
} else {
    $.backstretch("http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/boat-ocean-railing-2719-527x350.jpg", {
        duration: 3000,
        fade: 750
    });
}
});
```

You can find it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98t21Le8/), too.

Answer (score -1):

When I tried it and reversed the order

> `viewportWidth < 768` vs `versus < viewportWidth`
>
> `viewportWidth < 1024` versus `1024 < viewportWidth`

it appears to work properly.